# Getting started with autotools

Tags: c, resources, build, build-automation, autotools

Anyone recommend how a person could get started with autotools in building a C project?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Follow the [autotools tutorial](http://www.lrde.epita.fr/~adl/autotools.html).

You can also get the [autobook](http://sources.redhat.com/autobook/download.html). Chapter 4 covers a minimal GNU autotools project.

Comment: Really, I dislike the autobook - I found Alexandre Duret-Lutz's tutorial more helpful and actually has the form of a tutorial, just my 2 cents.

Comment: Agreed, adl's tutorial is way better, but checking out the autobook does not hurt.

Comment: Am i missing something or is this 'tutorial' a set of power-point-style slides?

Comment: The first link gives me a "This Connection is Untrusted" error.

Comment: Yeah, looks like their certificate is now signed by their own self-signed certificate. Ignore the warning and proceed. The tutorial is still there :-)

Answer (score 46):

[Alexandre Duret-Lutz](http://www.lrde.epita.fr/~adl/autotools.html)'s tutorial is my resource of choice.

There are also:

- [Autotools: a practitioner's guide to Autoconf, Automake and Libtool](http://www.freesoftwaremagazine.com/books/autotools_a_guide_to_autoconf_automake_libtool)
- [Autotools Mythbuster](http://www.flameeyes.eu/autotools-mythbuster/)

To me, the [autobook](http://sources.redhat.com/autobook/) is not up to date anymore and more difficult to read. However  it still contains interesting chapters like [Writing Portable Bourne Shell](https://www.sourceware.org/autobook/autobook/autobook_117.html#Writing-Portable-Bourne-Shell).

Also, consider learning about [non-recursive automake](http://www.flameeyes.eu/autotools-mythbuster/automake/nonrecursive.html) which addresses the concerns raised by Peter Miller in his [Recursive Make Considered Harmful](http://aegis.sourceforge.net/auug97.pdf) article.

EDIT: for reference, there is also [Autotools Tutorial for Beginners](http://markuskimius.wikidot.com/programming:tut:autotools/).

Comment: seriously? I got -1 for my answer while being the most exhaustive one... you can't be serious

Comment: Well, ten months later, you get a +1 for being, as far as I'm concerned, the best answer.

Comment: Another +1 for the reference to the online version of practitioner's guide.  I have the book at home, but sometimes need the info at work as well.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend [this tutorial](http://www.freesoftwaremagazine.com/books/autotools_a_guide_to_autoconf_automake_libtool) and get [the book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1593272065) when it's released. The tutorial really helped me a lot, it even contains a step by step conversion of an existing (non trivial) project to autotools.

Answer (score 3):

This is a good place to start:

http://www.dwheeler.com/autotools/ - video tutorial: Introduction to the Autotools (2012-03-05)

He makes a very good point "Beware any documentation written before 2006 is probably out of date."

After that:

http://www.lrde.epita.fr/~adl/autotools.html - autotools tutorial (556 slides)
http://www.openismus.com/documents/linux/automake/automake - Using Automake and Autoconf with C++

Answer (score 1):

I found this tutorial given by [Thomas Petazzoni](https://stackoverflow.com/users/643208/thomas-petazzoni) at the Embedded Linux Conference 2016 very helpful to start learning autotools:
[Autotools: A Demystification Tutorial](https://youtu.be/_zX8LJ9Xjyk)

Here are the associated slides:
[GNU Autotools Tutorial Slides](http://events.linuxfoundation.org/sites/events/files/slides/petazzoni-autotools-tutorial.pdf)

He gives demonstrations and good examples that are in my opinion a good start before going further with the already mentioned [A. Duret-Lutz tutorial](https://www.lrde.epita.fr/~adl/autotools.html).