# How to go about adding unit tests to an established (autotools) C project

Tags: c, unit-testing, autotools

I have a fork of openssh with some new features and want to write some unit tests to make sure they work at build. Grafting Check into openssh's autotools configuration is diffacult (because I don't really understand autotools)

Is there an easier to use C unit test framework? One less closely tied to autotools? 
How about a better way of going about adding Check to this project with out radically changing its build files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might not be a good idea to move away from autotools if the objective is to integrate those new features in the main branch. This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746135) is pointing to several tutorials for autotools that could be helpful.

Otherwise, there are several unit framework available for C: the most notorious are Cunit, Check, minunit, CMockery, refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65820) or [this list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unit_testing_frameworks#C).