# Autotools compiler

Tags: c++, c, autotools, autoconf, automake

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting started with autotools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746135/getting-started-with-autotools)

I am trying to use autotools to compile C and C++ files included.  Can anyone point me in the right direction to some documentation on how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: @TomKerr: We don't tell the folks learning C to use Java instead, and we don't tell people asking about SVN to use Git instead.  Please restrict such commentary to your blog.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at these links:

- http://www.developingprogrammers.com/index.php/2006/01/05/autotools-tutorial/
- http://www.lrde.epita.fr/~adl/autotools.html
- http://www.openismus.com/documents/linux/automake/automake.shtml

Answer (score 2):

First, if you are integrating C and C++, remember that you are building a C++ project with some C compatible symbols exported.  If that statement doesn't make a lot of sense to you, the better explanation [is found here](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/mixing-c-and-cpp.html).

There are many good autoconf tutorials.  Start off small, and don't be afraid to peek into other open-source projects for hints and tips as to how they solved making some library easily configurable.

http://www.openismus.com/documents/linux/automake/automake.shtml

http://sourceware.org/autobook/autobook/autobook_toc.html

Comment: +1 for the Goat Book link. It's very comprehensive.

Comment: Sadly, openismus closed down in 2014 and the web is no longer available

Comment: @AlejandroBlasco The wayback machine to the rescue! https://web.archive.org/web/20140227134152/http://www.openismus.com/documents/linux/automake/automake.shtml

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend Automake and Autoconf 
The easiest and more effective autotools
http://www.openismus.com/documents/linux/automake/automake

Answer (score -1):

I heard about Cmake recently, looks like it's a great tool, KDE switched to using it.