# Add libraries to linux g++ compiler

Tags: c++, linux, g++

I have the OPENCV and BLOBS library seen by the compiler as they were build with make
But how can I add the pylon5 and libxl libraries which does not need to be make to be seen by the g++ compiler without the code::blocks and make it permanent

Comment: Where did you get the libraries? Do they have instructions on their websites?

Comment: Yes they works fantastcly in code::blocks but when I try to open the execute file nothing happend and the terminal is telling me that I miss this libraries how to link them permenantly (like environmental varieble "path" in windows)

Comment: The compiler has nothing to do with running the program. You want the libraries to be seen by the **program** not the compiler. You can set `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/my/library` (separate paths using a colon `:` ).

Comment: Its not a permenent solution and I still need the terminal is there somthing to be done so that it will be permenent and that I could just click twice on the icon without the need of terminal?

Comment: I generally [write a script](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/linux-shell-scripting-lessons/) to run the program, or else set it to run in the `IDE`. However, ultimately you may want to **install** the program. That means you put the libraries in system places where the system can find them (or get the package management system to do it). That is beyond the scope of an answer here. For that you should look up the documentation for your distribution. Or use a build system that incorporates it like [Autotools](https://elinux.org/images/4/43/Petazzoni.pdf).

Comment: More Autotools info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746135/getting-started-with-autotools